# Sublime Text 3 Word Wrap (set as default) no longer working

Tags: editor, sublimetext3, sublimetext, word-wrap

These are my sublime text custom settings:

```
{
    "auto_complete_triggers":
    [
        {
            "characters": ".",
            "selector": "source.js"
        }
    ],
    "auto_match_enabled": false,
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme",
    "font_size": 10,
    "save_on_focus_lost": true,
    "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "word_wrap": true
}
```

As you can see word wrap is properly enabled. The only way to enable word - wrap is to do it on a per file basis, by going to View -> Word Wrap (tick). This setting was working fine a while ago. Now apparently something has happened and it's no longer working. Can't remember what it was, other than installing a plugin. Help.

Comment: Does it not work in all files of all types, or only in files of certain types? Perhaps you have set a syntax specific setting?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found the answer. Should have searched more before i post this question, but anyway. Word wrap worked for some extensions but not for others (indeed few ones). So for the latter ones, i added the following:

```
"ignored_packages":
[
    "Vintage"
],
"word_wrap": true
```

into the custom settings of Preferences -> Settings - Syntax Specific

Now everything works.